# Twilio Video with Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, twilio, typescript-typings

I created a component with Angular 2 and Typescript that allow create a video calls using a library Twilio Video. I trying to create a custom typing for typescript of library twilio-video, the way used in other posts like:

```
declare var Twilio:any;
```

work for my only when I used a twilio client library, but not with twilio video.

```
interface Twilio {
  //Other declarations here
  Video: any;
}
declare namespace Twilio {
  //Others interface here like Connection and Device from client library
  interface Video {
    connect(token: string, options?:Object): Promise;
    createLocalTracks(options?:Object): Promise;
    //Other declarations of methods
  }
}
```

and finally can declare:

```
declare var Twilio:Twilio;
```

With these custom type work a video call, I can create a room and create a local tracks, but cannot use a disable or enable methods from LocalTrack, I review a code of library twilio-video and read about create custom types and I think that the library is necesary used a template like that [show here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-class-d-ts.html), something like that:

```
export as namespace Twilio;
export = Video;

declare class Video {
  connect(token:string, options: Object): Promise;
  createLocalTracks(options?: Object): Promise;
  //Other declarations of functions of Video
}

declare namespace Video {
   export interface LocalVideoTrack {
       new(mediaStream:any, mediaStreamTrack:any, options:Object);
       disable():void;
       enable():void;
   }
}
```

That way can used as namespace Twilio, but cannot declare nothing using Twilio.Video as library used, I cannot use instanceof to cast a var, and don't have relationship with the code of library.

The primary problem for me is that I cannot declare correctly a custom typescript typing that used all functions declared in twilio video library. I am new using typescript only a few weeks ago.